# How do you syncronize javascript modules at different ajax levels?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Module pattern:

```
APP.MODULE.MYMODULE = (function(OTHERMODULE) {

   //ajax call with new module initialization

}(APP.MODULE.OTHERMODULE));
```

Let's assume that there is a lot of ajax module initializations of different levels. How do you syncronize javascript modules **at different ajax levels**?

The actualt problem is:

```
 APP.MODULE.OTHERMODULE // is underfined if OTHERMODULE is initialize on ajax request 
 // and we can't pass undefined object as a dependency
```

It feels like passing into a another module APP.MODULE 'namespace' with not initialize OTHERMODULE is a bad practice. Also javascript file reordering takes a lot of time as well as circle dependencies.

Do you init new modules on success or done ajax result? How do you organize the code in files?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at requirejs. then you can say things like

```
define ("MYMODULE", ["OTHERMODULE"], (other){
/* your code depeinding on othermodule here */
});
```

this way you can keep your modules pure and manage dependencies